# python 16bit grayscale video from series of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have a dataset of grayscale images of type uint16 and I would like to save it as a video file,
the output should be lossless video file of type uint16, i tried this code,

```
video = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name, 0, fps, (w, h), isColor=False)
for frame in frames:
  video.write(frame)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but opencv support only uint8,
anyone know a good way to do it?

Comment: I am unaware of any video format anywhere that can store 16-bit lossless grey. Someone please say, and ping me, if such a thing exists. You could simply append a bunch of lossless 16-bit NetPBM PGM format images together in a file and **ImageMagick** (and probably `ffmpeg`) would understand them.

Comment: Do you know a compressed video format? The uint16 is more important to me

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this video? Even the latest, greatest £5,000 Apple XDR Pro Display is only 10-bit AFAIK.

Comment: It's for a research in deep learning if i will convert it to uint8, I will loss important data

Comment: What program are you expecting to read it with in order to analyse it? What video format/extension is that program expecting?

Comment: To tag the data, I need video file (avi for example), but the input for the model will be numpy array.

Comment: If I will convert it to yuv (y16), it will work?

Comment: AVI cannot store 16-bit greyscale AFAIK. Please provide a link to such a file if you know of one, and also say where it came from and how it was made. Thank you.

Comment: This seems like a custom format. Can't you just map those 16 bits on two 8-bit colors in a common format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with FFMPEG. The **FFV1** codec is **lossless** and supports **gray16le** pixel format (images in 16UC1). You can make a .avi video.

```
ffmpeg -i depth_%06d.tif -c:v ffv1 -vf -crf 0 output_ffv1.avi
```

However, your images must be in **gray16le** format (saving images as .tif will work). If your images are in PNG they probably won't be in **gray16le** format but in **grey** format (this won't work if you want to get images from the video later). You can check with ffprobe.

```
ffprobe -i depth_image.png
```

Output must have something like:

```
Stream 0:0: Video: tiff, gray16le, 1280x720, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Once you have your video (.avi), you can check the pixel format again with ffprobe, it must be **gray16le** too.

```
Stream 0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), gray16le, 1280x720, 45067 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

Now, if you want to get the images back from the video. You can use [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python). This extracts unit16 arrays from the video. Then you can save this array as PNG or TIFF or whatever you need.

```
import ffmpeg
def extract_frame(input_vid, frame_num):
   out, _ = (
       ffmpeg
       .input(input_vid)
       .filter_('select', 'gte(n,{})'.format(frame_num))
       .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='gray16le', vframes=1)
       .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
   )
   return np.frombuffer(out, np.uint16).reshape([720, 1280])
 
for i in range($totalFrameNumber):
   frame = extract_frame('test_ffv1.avi',i)
```

Change $totalFrameNumber for the total number of frames in your .avi video.

Comment: Cool - do you know which software/players/viewers are able to play back such a 16-bit video please?

Comment: Well... I use Ubuntu 20 and I'm able to reproduce the .avi video with the player. However, the image that is shown has a black background and a lot of noise (nothing recognizable as well as the images, they are mostly black). I think if you have these type of images (grayscale 16UC1), there are not meant for visualization. In my case, there are depth maps, each pixel is a distance in mm. Making a video is just for making this info compatible for some applications. For example, software that only receives a video as an input.