# Converting sequence of .tiff 16bit grayscale images to .avi

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a sequence of `.tiff` 16 bit grayscale images that I need to convert to video without losing any of the information (I'm just trying to reduce the number of files I'll have to store). I tried using `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i frame_%d.tiff -c:v ffv1 -vf -crf 0 output.avi` but I'm getting an error

```
Input #0, image2, from 'frame_%d.tiff':
  Duration: 00:00:31.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: tiff, gray16le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[NULL @ 0x56208c45b640] Unable to find a suitable output format for '0'
0: Invalid argument
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `-vf` by itself is a syntax error. What's its purpose?

Comment: I was following the instructions in this answer from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604533

Comment: Remove `-vf`...